# Firestore Security Rules - On create, check attribute is not in another document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firestore and have users that contain an attribute called domain:

```
{ 
    domain: "@domain.com"
}
```

I am currently using cloud functions to generate a random domain for the user on signup. The cloud function queries the database in order to check whether the random domain already exists or not, which causes a few seconds of delay.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the insertion of a new user if another user already exists with that domain from the Firestore Security Rules only without having to query the entire database?

So far I've tried adding this to my security rules, but it allows for duplicates:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{Id} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(Id)).data.domain != request.resource.data.domain;
  }
}
```

Any idea whether this is feasible or not using just the security rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if a collection already exists in *any* other document in a collection. If you think about it for a moment that makes sense - such an operation would be very costly.

What you *can* do is check if a document with a specific ID already exists in a collection. The typical solution for your type of problem is therefor to create a collection where you use the domain as the ID.

E.g.

```
users
  user1: { domain: "@domain.com" }
  user2: { domain: "@other.com" }
domains
  "domain.com": "user1"
  "other.com": "user2"
```

Now your security rules can check whether the domain is already claimed in the `/domains` collection.

Note that you'll want to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to perform updates, since `/users` and `/domains` must always be kept in sync in this approach.